# Placeholder fix for IE8 / IE9: Works the first time, stops working on refresh / partial refresh

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, xpages, placeholder

I had posted about how you can [enable placeholders](http://xpagesandme.wordpress.com/2014/07/25/dabbling-in-bootstrap-and-font-awesome-part-4-holding-a-special-place-in-my-field-placeholders-and-ie8-ie9/) in IE8 / IE9 in my blog. I am using the jquery.placeholder.js.

When the page first loads, everything is working fine. The placeholders are displayed properly and when you jump / click into the field, the placeholder disappears:

[image: Placeholder shown]

[image: Placeholder disappears when field is active]

However, if I do a partial refresh or refresh, the placeholder becomes the value/content of the field and won't disappear when I click into it:

[image: Placeholder becomes value/content of field]

I tried using XSP.addOnLoad at the end of the div I am doing the partial refresh on:

```
XSP.addOnLoad($(function() { $('input, textarea').placeholder();}))
```

But I am getting an error message when I debug in the browser:

[image: Error message]

I also tried to add the code to the onComplete of the event, but no luck.

The placeholder fix works the first time around, but doesn't play nicely with XPages refreshes.

Any idea or push in the right direction would be highly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Remove the first `$` in `XSP.addOnLoad($(function() { $('input, textarea').placeholder();}))` it should be `XSP.addOnLoad((function() { $('input, textarea').placeholder();}))`

Comment: Hello Adam, thank you very much for your response, I appreciate it. This fixed the error message I was getting, however, it didn't fix the general issue of the placeholders working the first time as expected but on the second go around, the placeholders become the field value / content and don't behave like placeholders anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think XSP.addOnLoad() adds the given function to the onload event of the XPage's body. This means that the function is only executed on load, but not after a partial refresh. You should replace the div with the XSP.addOnLoad() by a (xp:)panel which executes your placeholder function in its **onClientLoad** event. In this way, the placeholder should be instantiated every time the panel gets refreshed.

Comment: Hello xpages-noob, thank you very much for your response, I appreciate it. Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. It applies the placeholders properly the first time, but when I do a partial refresh, the placeholder text becomes the field's value / content.